# Format currency dynamically on TextView

Tags: android, format, currency

I'm trying to dynamically format the value entered by the user on a `TextView`, specifically what I am trying to do is:

```
1. TextView text = ""
2. User entered = "4"
3. TextView text = 0.04
4. User entered = "5"
5. TextView text = 0.45
6. User entered = "6"
7. TextView text = 4.56
```

and so on...

I'm using the `onTextChanged`method stub from `TextWatcher`, although I don't know how to implement this logic.

What is the simplest way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `NumberFormat` in this case, e.g:

```
double moneyCurrency = 100.1;
NumberFormat baseFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String moneyString = baseFormat.format(moneyCurrency);
```